# Problems displaying google heat map

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, heatmap

Hope you can help me with the below code. I'm having issues getting the heatmap to load in Chrome but it does load in IE (after refresh) hope you can provide me a/some pointers to check as im new to google maps, JS and JSON  :-)

thank you!

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Phone Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization&key=****"></script>
    <script>
        var map,heatmap;
        var markers = [];
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "../src/et.json";

        function initialize() {
            // Create a simple map.
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                zoom: 3,
                center:  new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
            });

            getMarkers(url);

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: markers
            });

            heatmap.setMap(map);
        }

        function getMarkers(url){
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    loadMarkers(myArr);
                }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function loadMarkers(arr) {
            var out = "";
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].latitude,arr[i].longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng
                });
                    markers.push(latLng);
            }
        }
    }



    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>

          <div id="map-canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What issues are you getting?

Comment: the markers/heatmap is not showing

Comment: I think it has somethign to do with the data not being ready from the external call while the map is loaded. I dont have this issue though when using the same external data and clustering markers on the map

Comment: I resolved this by moving heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: markers
            });

            heatmap.setMap(map); 

to the loadMarkers function